How to match the index of tensors and values in the list using pytorch?
I'd like to match the index of tensors from the list.
I'm trying to do link prediction using Pytorch.
In this process, I need to convert the index to the name by mapping it to the dictionary.
To do this, I set the dictionary and masking to the tensor, but it returned unexpected indices.
inv_entity_dict = {v: k for k, v in entity_dict.items()}
inv_entity_dict
#{0: 'TMEM35A',
# 1: 'FHL5',
# 2: 'Sirolimus',
# 3: 'TMCO2',
# 4: 'RNF123',
# 5: 'SMURF2',
# 6: 'SSH3',
# 7: 'PSMA4',
# 8: 'SOD3',
# 9: 'SCOC',
# 10: 'Cysteamine',
# 11: 'TOX',
#...}

nonzero[0:10]
#array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 11])

After running the code, it returned unexpected results because Sirolimus(idx==2), which is not in the nonzero array, should not be matched the name.
for i in range(1):
    raw_probs = (z[i][nonzero[0:10]] @ z[i][nonzero[0:10]].t()).sigmoid()
    filtered_probs = pd.DataFrame((raw_probs>0.9).nonzero(as_tuple=False).cpu().numpy(), columns=['Gene1', 'Gene2'])
    filtered_probs['prob'] = raw_probs[(raw_probs>0.9)].cpu().detach().numpy()
    filtered_probs_name = map_id2gene(filtered_probs, inv_entity_dict) #converting func.

#Expected result
#   Gene1   Gene2   prob
#67 TOX TOX 1.0
#0  TMEM35A TMEM35A 1.0
#1  TMEM35A FHL5    1.0
#2  TMEM35A RNF123  1.0
#52 SCOC    TMEM35A 1.0

#Wrong
#   Gene1   Gene2   prob
#67 SCOC    SCOC    1.0
#0  TMEM35A TMEM35A 1.0
#1  TMEM35A FHL5    1.0
#2  TMEM35A Sirolimus   1.0
#52 SOD3    TMEM35A 1.0

I guess the initialized raw_probs indices went into the converting process directly.
raw_prob
#tensor([[1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 0
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 1
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 3, but considered to 2
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 4, but considered to 3, ...
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 5
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 6
#        [0.0000e+00, ..., 0.0000e+00], #real index: 7
#        [0.0000e+00, ..., 4.4097e-36], #real index: 8
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00], #real index: 9
#        [1.0000e+00, ..., 1.0000e+00] #real index: 11, but considered to 9], device='cuda:0')

In this case, how can I match the correct ids and names based on the inv_entity_dict and nonzero list?

Okay, I just add the new dictionary like this:
d = dict(enumerate(map(int, nonzero)))

filtered_probs['Gene1'] = filtered_probs.apply(lambda L: d[L.iloc[0]], axis=1)
filtered_probs['Gene2'] = filtered_probs.apply(lambda L: d[L.iloc[1]], axis=1)

Then it returns the correct result.
If you have any better opinions, please feel free to comment!
